# How do I stop the toggle event when a submenu item is clicked?

Tags: jquery

I have a sidebar menu. Each menu item has sub-menus. It is created dynamically. Here is the code:

```
 <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <?php
            $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','Dmenu2');
            $sql="SELECT * FROM menu" ;
            $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            if( $row['parent_id']==0){
            $cat_id=$row['id'];
            $cat_name=$row['name'];
            echo "<li><a>".$cat_name."</a>";
            echo "<ul class='sub-menu'>";
            $sql2="SELECT * FROM menu WHERE parent_id=$cat_id";
            $result2=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error());

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
            $sub_cat_id=$row['id'];
            $sub_cat_name=$row['name'];
            $sub_cat_target=$row['target'];
            echo "<li><a href='".$sub_cat_target."'>".$sub_cat_name."</a></li>";           
             }
            echo "</ul>";
            echo "</li>";
            }

      }
  ?>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

My jQuery is like this: (for the toggling):

```
$('.sub-menu').hide();
$("li:has(ul)").click(function(){
$("ul",this).toggle('slow');
});
```

When I click on a sub-menu item, I do not want the entire sub-menu to toggle up, instead I want that particular sub-menu to be highlighted. Each sub-menu item is linked to a separate page which loads in the page-content-wrapper div.

```
  $(function () {
        $('.sub-menu a').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#page-content-wrapper').load(page);

        });

    });
```

How do I stop the toggling when a sub-menu item is clicked? I have tried to unbind the click of sub-menu, using the stop() function, but none of it works.

Comment: `$(this).children('ul').toggle('slow');`???

Comment: where should I place this? I'm sorry but I'm only a beginner.

Comment: Instead of `$("ul",this).toggle('slow');`

Comment: i tried replacing my $("ul",this).toggle('slow'); with ur code, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: nope not happening. When I click on a sub-menu item, the sub-menu goes up :(